# Prove if $|z|,|w|<1 $, then $|\frac{z-w}{1-zw}|<1 $ and if $|w|=|z|=1 $, then $\frac{z-w}{1-zw}\in{\Re}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove:

> If $|z|,|w|<1$, then $\left|\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}\right|<1$.

Not quite sure how to approach this.. I've tried squaring it and to do something from there:

$$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}\right|^2<1^2$$
or
$$\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}*\overline{\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}}<1$$

I started to multiply all the $z$ and $w$ but then it appears that I reached a dead end.

Also the second part is,
Prove:

> If $|w|=|z|=1$, then $\frac{z-w}{1-zw}\in{\Re}$.

Don't have a clue on this one..

Comment: For the first part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190613/42969.

Comment: Looks like my book has a mistake because in the link you just gave, the lower $w$ is a conjugent $w$, looks like that is the correct way to write the exercise.

Comment: $\left|\frac{z-w}{1-zw}\right|<1$ (as written in the question, without conjugating $w$ in the denominator) is actually *wrong:* try $z = i/2, w = -i/2$.

Comment: Very nice, I'll edit it accordingly, thanks a lot - been breaking my head on some book's mistake XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $|w|=|z|=1$

$\frac{z-w}{1-wz}=\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{w}}{1-\bar{z}\bar{w}}$

But:

$(1-\bar{w}\bar{z})(z-w)=z-\bar{w}-w+\bar{z}=(\bar{z}-\bar{w})(1-zw)$

From this calculation we have that the above fractional complex number is equal to its conjugate,thus it is a real number.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part:

You only need to show that for $r = \frac{z-w}{1-z w}$ holds $\bar r = r$.

We have 
$$|z| = |w|= 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{z} = \bar z \mbox{ and } \frac{1}{w} = \bar w$$

Now,

$$\bar r = \frac{\bar z - \bar w}{1-\bar z \bar w} = \frac{\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{w}}{1-\frac{1}{zw}} = \frac{w - z}{wz-1} = r$$
So, second part is also done.

Comment: when you say  $r = \frac{z+w}{1+z w}$, you meant $$r = \frac{z-w}{1-z w}$$

right?

Comment: Yessss. Thanks for mentioning it. Edited it correspondingly.